# IDA pro not displaying assemply code like ollyDBG

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

i'm new to using IDA
i'm trying to check game code but it's not showing me the right address which i find with memory search while the game is running and it does not show me the code as OllyDBG
anything i'm missing?

[screenshot for what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LV5q.jpg)

Comment: With pressing `c` you can change the type. Right now IDA identified this as data - if you think it's wrong and it's code then change it

Comment: It's not unheard of for game engines to try to make hacking harder. Like encrypting parts of the code, so that a disassembled exe looks nothing like the actual running code.

Comment: Bo Persson , i didn't understand well what do you mean ,hope you can explain it in more clear way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget that IDA is a *static* disassembler (albeit very smart one), while OllyDBG is a *dynamic* debugger.

A debugger sees a program that is loaded into memory and is about to be run or is paused in the middle of its execution. A disassembler does not run a program, but tries to decode its code and data as they are represented in a disk file image. What is stored on a disk may be different from what gets found in RAM, especially if there are dynamic modules loaded eagerly at start or lazily later, or if there are decoding/decryption stages in program's operation.

Not to mention that IDA is a powerful tool that has some learning curve.

P.S. a great book about using "The IDA Pro Book, 2nd Edition": https://nostarch.com/idapro2.htm

Comment: ida is a debugger aswell

Comment: @K3rnel31 true, but the core function of IDA is static binary analysis. One can also use IDA as binary editor, or even as text editor, or as assembler to write programs, or as something  else (e.g. as decompiler, with a plugin), but these are its secondary functions.